# Can't reuse a template in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, chart.js, browserify

Trying to reuse a custom template from my Graph.vue file, but this attempt fails(without any errors in the console). I only get one chart rendered(the red one). Any ideas how to fix this code?

My current code looks like this:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Graph from './components/Graph.vue';

new Vue({
    el: 'graph',
    components: { Graph }
});
```

Graph.vue

```
<template>
    <canvas height="400" width="600"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
    import Chart from 'chart.js';

    export default {
        props: ['labels', 'values', 'color'],
        props: {
            labels: {},
            values: {},
            color: {
                default: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)'
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            var data = {
                labels: this.labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        fill: true,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: this.color,
                        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        borderDash: [],
                        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointBorderWidth: 1,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointRadius: 1,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        data: this.values,
                        spanGaps: false
                    },
                ]
            };

            new Chart(this.$el, {type: 'line', data: data});
        }
    }
</script>
```

example.html

```
 <div style="width:600px" class="container">

            <graph :labels="['January', 'February', 'March']"
                   :values="[10, 42, 4]"
                   color="red"
            ></graph>
        </div>
        <div style="width:600px" class="container">

            <graph :labels="['May', 'June', 'July']"
                   :values="[100, 420, 99]"
                   color="blue"
            ></graph>
        </div>
<script src="{{asset('/js/main.js')}}"></script>
```

The intended result should be two bars - red and blue one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your mountpoint is wrong. `el: 'graph'` behavior is probably not predictable in this context (will it target the first graph element?).

Use something like that instead:

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#graphContainer',
    components: { Graph }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="graphContainer">
  <div style="width:600px" class="container>
    <graph :labels="['January', 'February', 'March']"
    :values="[10, 42, 4]"
    color="red"></graph>
  </div>
  <div style="width:600px" class="container">
    <graph :labels="['May', 'June', 'July']"
    :values="[100, 420, 99]"
    color="blue"></graph>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @Cobaltway answer better, but this also solves the problem.
**JS:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Graph from './components/Graph.vue';

const graphs = document.querySelectorAll('graph');

for (let i = 0; i < graphs.length; ++i) {
    new Vue({
        el: graphs[i],
        components: { Graph }
    });
}
```